# Is there a reason that std::string methods have a diffrent style than rest of STL

Tags: c++, string, stl

I always wondered why string methods are different compared to those of other containers ,for example std::map...
one example what I mean by that is this:

```
size_t find (char c, size_t pos = 0) const
```

note that return value is not an iterator.
So is there a some "legit" reason why std::string is like that, beside obvious: committee made a bubu, string is broken...

BTW I know some ppl dont consider string part of STL, you can just pretend I asked why string is different from containers in std?

Comment: See the old [Herb Sutter](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1661064/herb-sutter) article [Monoliths: Unstrung](http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/084.htm)

Comment: @Salgar my question wasnt about that specific function, but the A on that Q is actually what I wanted to know... autoclosing my Q

Comment: STL stands for Standard Template Library. You can think of a string as an application of vector<char>, therefore it's not even on the same level as any of those containers.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

**Because std::string is not a container and those operations are commonly used.**

Rather you can think of it as specialization of a container. `std::vector<char>`. Designed for a specific use. And provides methods which are useful for that type and usage.

Think of it like this, why even `std::string`? why not use `std::vector<char>` when you want to represent strings? Simply **convenience**.

Comment: Still it otherwise adheres to the usual container interface.

Comment: @ChristianRau But it is not a container. The question is like why is std::string is even  there? (why is std::vector<char> not enough?)

Comment: Nobody argues about the neccessity for things like `find_first_not_of` or `substr`, still this doesn't answer why they don't work with iterators if the other half of `std::string`'s container functions do (which is actually the question the OP asked, not why `std::string::find` and friends are there at all , which seems to be the question you're answering).

Comment: @ChristianRau Yes I see your point. But if you want the features that you mentioned, there is always `vector<char>`. `string` exists because it is convenient for most "string" operations. For example when I do find on string I would rather get size_t rather than the more verbose iterator. considering how often you manipulate strings there is nothing wrong with providing a convenient method.

Comment: Valid point, but this isn't what you're answer is saying.